# Convert text in hex form to characters in C

Tags: c, encryption

I am trying to decrypt a cipher text in C. The cipher text appeared to be in form of symbols and unreadable characters and I was unable to read the cipher text stored in this from a file properly hence the decryption was failing. So I tried a different method where I stored the cipher text in form of hexadecimal by doing:

```
sprintf(file,"%02x",ciphertxt(//symbols));
```

Now I am able to read the comple te cipher text in hexadecimal form. But in order to decrypt it I need to pass it to openssl decryption function in its pure symbolic form only. How can I change back the hexadecimal form to the original symbolic character form?

Comment: Why wasn't you able to read the file? How was you doing it?

Comment: When the file was storing the encrypted text I was only able to read the partial contents hence the decryption was failing. This might have been due to while reading file it encountered a null value in the encrypted text and hence stopped reading further.

Comment: You're still thinking of programming in terms of strings;  you have to get used to dealing with binary data otherwise it'll continue to bite you.  First off, learn how to read binary files directly (no need to mess around with hex) e.g.. http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-binary-file-io .  Remember that you'll be dealing with a binary array, so you can't use string functions like strcpy or strlen;  instead, you'll have to keep track yourself how much data is in the array (hint: fread returns how much was read).  Good luck !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
unsigned char numbuf[3];
unsigned long i, j;
unsigned char outbuf[BUFFERSIZE]

numbuf[2] = 0; // terminate buffer
i = 0;
j = 0;
while(filebuf[i] && j < BUFFERSIZE - 1)
{
    numbuf[0] = filebuf[i];
    numbuf[1] = filebuf[i+1];
    outbuf[j++] = strtol(numbuf, NULL, 16);
    i+=2; // each value is two bytes long
}
outbuf[j] = 0;
```

Comment: This is a nice simply starting code for OP  (missing various error checking and limits)